# how to list deleted directory names in a path?

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, directory, undelete

I accidentally deleted a directory in home folder, I don't want to recover it, I only want to make sure if I deleted the right directory.

Is there any way to know the name of deleted directory in a path?

Comment: Couldn't you just run `ls` and confirm that it's no longer there?

Comment: @wjandrea I am unsure if I deleted the right folder, I confused its name, If I see the name of deleted folder I can figure out which one I deleted.

Comment: Deleted how? if you used the command line, you can look in your shell's history

Comment: You could run a file recovery program, then check the names of folders it finds before actually doing the restore.

Comment: @wjandrea I tried photorec, once I used it to recover deleted files in external disk and it listed deleted folders by directory hierarchy, but this time it doesn't show like that, I forgot how to do that.